# Characteristic of infinite integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Give an example of infinite integral domain that has characteristic 3.

I know the result which states that finite integral domain has characteristic either 0 or prime.We have example of infinite integral domain that is $\Bbb Z$ but it has characteristic $0$.I am stuck here how to form an example of infinite integral domain with characteristic 3?

Comment: Just as a side remark: a non-zero finite ring with $1$ without non-zero zero-divisors is always a field. And the fact that the characteristic is either $0$ or prime holds for all non-zero rings with $1$ without non-zero zero-divisors (commutative or not, finite or not).

Answer (score 3):

You can consider the ring $R = \mathbb{F}_3[x]$ of univariate polynomials over the finite field of $3$ elements. As $\mathbb{F}_3$ is a field, thus an integral domain, $R$ will be an integral domain too, and it will have characteristic $3$. Clearly, $R$ is infinite.

Comment: Yes,I got it.I can take $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ as a example.

Comment: Indeed. By the way, this example works for any prime characteristic $p$ (just replace $\mathbb{Z}_3$ by $\mathbb{Z}_p$).

Comment: How $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ is an integral domain? If we consider $x(x-1)$ and $(x-2)$ both are non-zero but $x(x-1)(x-2)$=$x^3-3x^2+2x$=$x+2x$=$0$.

Comment: @Rkb In $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, the symbol $x$ is an indeterminate, not an element of $\mathbb{Z}_3$. The equality $a^3 = a$ only holds for elements in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. The product $x(x - 1)(x - 2)$ thus becomes $x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x$, with no further simplifications possible.